# Different coordinate format in GeoJSON and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, geojson

As part of a government driven Open Data project, my city made some geodata accessible via Web Feature Service. A third party did convert some of this data to GeoJSON, so more people can make use of it. The data looks like that:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "Hauskoordinaten",
  "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
  "features": [
    { 
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 5,
      "properties": { 
        "objectid": "5",
        "strschl": "1",
        "adresse": "Aachener Str. *",
        "strname": "Aachener Str.",
        "x": "32359072.929",
        "y": "5701476.297"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.971984166915553,
          51.446915354002748
        ]
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature", "id": 6, "properties": { "objectid": "6", "strschl": "1", "hsnr": "1", "adresse": "Aachener Str. 1", "strname": "Aachener Str.", "x": "32359252.047", "y": "5701464.014" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.974564923492866, 51.446849521064742 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "id": 7, "properties": { "objectid": "7", "strschl": "1", "hsnr": "2", "adresse": "Aachener Str. 2", "strname": "Aachener Str.", "x": "32359267.632", "y": "5701483.058" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.974781475486739, 51.447024527120796 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "id": 8, "properties": { "objectid": "8", "strschl": "1", "hsnr": "3", "adresse": "Aachener Str. 3", "strname": "Aachener Str.", "x": "32359236.486", "y": "5701463.429" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.974341375868697, 51.446840396580718 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "id": 9, "properties": { "objectid": "9", "strschl": "1", "hsnr": "4", "adresse": "Aachener Str. 4", "strname": "Aachener Str.", "x": "32359252.073", "y": "5701482.515" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.97455793901083, 51.447015780957109 ] } }
  ]
}
```

If I load this data into a random online GeoJSON visualizer, it appears just fine.

If I try to enter these coordinates into Google Maps, I have to swap their order: `6.97455793901083, 51.447015780957109` is some random point in the ocean, `51.447015780957109, 6.97455793901083` is what I want and what looks right.

As someone that doesn't really have a clue of cartography, geography, map projections and so one: Why is that? Is the data in an unusual format? Does GeoJSON for whatever reason require the "swapped" format? Or is Google Maps the one that falls out of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering is different between GeoJSON and Google Maps.

There has long been disagreement (latitude/longitude vs. x/y). See [Geotools::Axis Order](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) for some history.

A position in [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) is defined as:

> **3.1.1.  Position**
> A position is an array of numbers.  There MUST be two or more
> elements.  **The first two elements are longitude and latitude**, or
> easting and northing, **precisely in that order and using decimal
> numbers**.

Google Maps (where not specified by name or object specification) uses the order latitude, longitude.

from: [Google Maps Help: Discover coordinates or search by latitude & longitude](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539)

> **Format your coordinates**
> To format your coordinates so they work in Google Maps, use decimal degrees in the following format:
> **Correct**: 41.40338, 2.17403
> **Incorrect**: 41,40338, 2,17403
> **Tips:**
> ***List your latitude coordinates before longitude coordinates***. (emphasis mine)